# Linux + why dropping issue displayed from ifconfig but not from ethtool?

Tags: linux, rhel, network-interface, ifconfig, systemd-networkd

we have Linux VM red hat 7.2 version with two LAN interfaces

the Linux machines are ruining on ESXi - 5.5.0

and we have very strange issue ,

the conflict is between the ifconfig command to ethtool command results!

why the results from ethtool isn't indicates on dropping problem on eth1

while from ifconfig I get the indicates that dropping problem exist on eth1?

( see ifconfig - increasing of numbers on dropped indicates on dropping error )

```
   # ethtool -S eth1 | grep -i drop
   drv dropped tx total: 0
   drv dropped tx total: 0
   drv dropped rx total: 0
   drv dropped rx total: 0
```

ifconfig results on eth1:

```
    # ifconfig -a | grep RX | grep dropped
    RX errors 0  dropped 123136  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 140938047  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    # ifconfig -a | grep RX | grep dropped
    RX errors 0  dropped 123136  overruns 0  frame 0
    RX errors 0  dropped 140938083  overruns 0  frame 0  <--------------  after second
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
```

second - is it true to except the results from ethtool as real results 
while the results from ifconfig actually inst indicate on problem?

remark - drooping problem are only displayed on Linux version 7.x and not on the other Linux version as 6.x or 5.x

Comment: You only show statistics for eth1. Is this the one with the drops (names are grepped out). Also, which driver are you using for eth1. It is probable that the drops are counted in different places.